# Setting the cursor of the android contact database on the specific ID

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-cursoradapter

I save some contact IDs in a database and I retrieve them in a list of Integers.

Then I try to set the cursor of the android contact database on the specific ID.
When I do it the LogCat informs me that the code crashes in

id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

I just try to set the cursor to point to the specific element of the database, and retrieve the name and the default phone number, without having to parse the whole contacts database.

What is wrong with the code? Thank you

```
            ArrayList<Contact> contactItemsTemp = new ArrayList<Contact>();

            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(BlacklistActivity.this);
            String name = "";
            String id = "";
            String phoneNumber = "";
            // Cursor cursor = null;

            List<Integer> mycontactID;
            mycontactID = db.getAllIDs();

            Iterator value = mycontactID.iterator();

            while (value.hasNext()) {
                int mg = (Integer) value.next();

                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
//              String[] PROJECTION=new String[] {  ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
//                      ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
//                      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
//                        };
                String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
                       // ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTACT_ID,
                };
            //   String where = Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID+" = "+mg+";

                //(
                Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                        PROJECTION ,  ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " = "+ Integer.toString(mg), null, null);

                //cur.moveToNext();
                if(cur.moveToNext())
                {
                    Log.d("edw", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                }

//              int indexName = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
    //            int indexPhoneType = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Phone.TYPE);

              //  int contactIdIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID)  ;  
               // int contactId = cur.getInt(contactIdIndex);    

                int indexID =  cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
                int indexName = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
                int indexPhoneType = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

                int contactId = cur.getInt(indexID); 
                int contactName = cur.getInt(indexName);
                int contactPhone = cur.getInt(indexPhoneType);

//                  if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
//                      while (cur.moveToNext()) {
//                          id = PROJECTION[0];
//                          name = PROJECTION[1];
//                          phoneNumber = PROJECTION[2];
//                                  
//                      }
//                  }


                id = cur.getString(contactId);
                name=cur.getString(contactName);
                phoneNumber=cur.getString(contactPhone);


//              id=PROJECTION[0];
//              name=PROJECTION[2];
//              phoneNumber=PROJECTION[3];


//              id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
//              name = cur
//                      .getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
//              phoneNumber = cur
//                      .getString(cur
//                              .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                contactItemsTemp.add(new Contact(Integer.parseInt(id), name, phoneNumber));
                cur.close();
}
```

Comment: @mkounal Why you want to store Contact in database?